# arrays rolling 2 dice

Tags: c++

Write a program that simulates the rolling of two dies. The sum of the two values should then be calculated and placed in a single-subscripted array. Print the array. Also find how many times 12 appear.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define SIZE 13
int main()
{
    int face;   
    int arraysize=13;       
    int counter[13];
    int frequency[ SIZE ]= {13};
    for(int i=0; i<13; i++)
        counter[i] = 0;

    int die1; 
    int die2;



    srand( time( NULL ) );


    for ( int roll1 = 0; roll1 <=36000; roll1++ ) {
        die1 =  1 + rand() % 6;
        die2 =  1 + rand() % 6;
        counter[die1+die2]++;
        ++frequency[ face ];
    }

    printf("%4s%17s\n","Sum of Values","Frequency");

    for(int face=2; face<arraysize;face++)
    {
            printf("%8d%17d\n",face,frequency[ face ]);
     }       

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

```
PRİNT SCREEN
Sum of Values        Frequency
       2            36001
       3                0
       4                0
       5                0
       6                0
       7                0
       8                0
       9                0
      10                0
      11                0
      12                0
```

Whats wrong ???

Comment: There are die or dice but no dices.

Comment: In addition to the answers below, you should not use modulo with rand(). It has a severe bias, see http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx and http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/random.html

Comment: Also, why have SIZE, arraysize and the literal 13 used to mean the same thing?

Answer (score 5):

This line

```
 ++frequency[ face ];
```

always increments the same location since the loop doesn't change the value of `face` you should be doing something like

```
++frequency[die1+die2];
```

Also I don't know what why you have both `frequency` and `counter` what is the difference?

Edit: Like it's been pointed out `face` isn't initialized at all (unless there is some code you removed).

Comment: +1 Also, `face` hasn't been initialised at that point. However, the array `frequency` always gets the same values as `counter` with your edit. I'm not sure that's intended.

Comment: @MrLister That's why I asked what the difference between `frequency` and `counter` is. I think they are the same thing (as he never uses `counter` again afterwards).

Comment: If face isn't initialized, why is it always adding to frequency[2] and not frequency[0]?

Comment: @pdr frequency[0] is equivalent to the dice value for 2 as that's the lowest value for a pair of dice.

Comment: @twain249 Yes. I also don't like how the arrays are initialised. What does the 13 stored in `frequency[0]` do? And since OP obviously knows how to initialise arrays, why is `counter` not initialised in the same way? Odd.

Comment: @pdr Uninitialised means it isn't set to 0. It can be anything. The OP should be thankful it's set to a decent value like that!

Comment: @twain249: I may be missing something really obvious here, but if the array is accessed using `for(int face=2;` then surely that's irrelevant.

Comment: @pdr I did not see that. You are correct then it is being set to frequency[2]. But like MrLister said unintialized doesn't = 0.

Comment: @MrLister: I thought C++ initialized to zero by default. If not, it's interesting that the frequency array (barring, I suspect, the [0] element, which would be 13) was initialized to zero.

Comment: @pdr That's how it works with arrays! If you write `int x[10] = {4, 5};` then the last 8 values will be set to zero. Only if you write `int x[10];` will it not get any values and will the contents be undetermined.

Comment: @pdr By the way, it's C, not C++. Just mistagged.

Comment: when i redefined size like 1 instead 13 it changed

Comment: @GfbAdanaGfb what? First was is the difference between the `counter` and `frequency` arrays supposed to be? Second what is the `face` variable used for?

Comment: when i used face as like a variable i thought die has 6 face idk does it matter?? face or other word instead of face

Comment: @GfbAdanaGfb the name of the variable doesn't matter at all. I just wanted to know what it's used for. All I see it being used as is a loop counter in the loop that prints out the answer. I didn't know if you had any other uses for it that I don't see.

Comment: and i have just 45 mins before send program to my instructure

Comment: @GfbAdanaGfb Ok so I would recommend printing out `counter` as the frequencies of the various numbers as it appears that it has all the correct values in it. if you want to figure out how many 12s there are just print `counter[12]/36000`

Comment: Thanks all of you for advices

Comment: @GfbAdanaGfb Are you actually trying to understand what's being explained here?

Answer (score 2):

```
++frequency[ face ];
```

`face` has not been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

You do not seem to initialize `face`.

Then you repeatedly access `frequency[ face ]`.

Answer (score 0):

`face` has not been initialised . Its always adding the frequency to same location and hence you get the count for only 1 of the sum of the two dice